# draw border surround country on which user clicked in openlayers

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers

I am working on openlayers application. One of the task that I am going to do is when user clicks on the map or any country, then It should select that map and outline that country by drawing a border in vector form. Is this possible? If yes then please give me some code links for examples.

Answer (score 0):

hi yes this is quite easily done. There are many ways to do so,

You will need to have a web service which will return the geojson (vector) boundary based on lat long passed.

on clinet side you will need to add a vector layer on top of your base map.

Assign a click handler on map (use a tool) and then on the click of the tool, call the web service passing the latlon , eventually when you get back the response from your web service inject the geojson to the vector layer.

Also look here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35395/how-to-highlight-a-selected-country